# Getting Segmentation Fault 11 due to RestKit on Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, restkit, macos-sierra

**Things Done**

- Upgraded Mac to Sierra
- Upgraded pods to 1.1.1 from 0.37.2
- Upgraded Restkit to 0.27.0

**Things Tried**

- Clearing DerivedData for Xcode
- Installing pods with xcode wordspace closed
- Restarting the Mac
- Adding User Header Search Path from related questions asked on here.

**Getting this error**

- file not found for Restkit

Comment: Can you copy in the full error message from the build? I assume you are getting the Segmentation Fault during the build process. Also try Xcode 8 if you haven't already -- older versions are not supported on Sierra.

Comment: Reskit will not work above pod version > 0.39.0

Comment: Why do you say that? With 0.27 it should be working fine with Cocoapods 1.0 or 1.1.

Comment: @EricHedstrom No it was not working with upgraded cocoapods. It says Restkit not found.

Comment: Please copy in the full error message from the build, and your RestKit entry from your Podfile. Make sure it has RestKit with a capital K.

Comment: @EricHedstrom : Its working now on cocoapods <= 0.39. As Restkit have some issues with the new cocoapods version.